# Update stock move record which is done odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am working in odoo 8, i have to update the stock move which is done. i.e. suppose the move was done and state becomes "done" but the quantity entered was incorrect, so to correct it i need to reduce the quantity of that move. 
I am trying to update the quantity but it gives me error as :

```
_('Quantities, Units of Measure, Products and Locations cannot be modified on stock moves that have already been processed (except by the Administrator).'))
```

I was trying as below:

```
move.write({'product_uos_qty':correct_qty})
```

I also tried this:

```
move.sudo().write({'product_uos_qty':correct_qty})
```

Always i get the same error.

Please Help

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/have-you-find-an-app-module-to-cancel-done-stock-moves-75807

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without getting into security or removing the constrains or restrictions Odoo put in place is to use sql. Just write the raw sql that accomplishes your task and execute it where you were trying to do your write above. Not sure if it is the best way. But in your addon you can inherit stock.move and completely override the function. Or just edit the file manually and restart your server. Not sure about the other problems it might cause but it should let your write to the field.

```
sql = ".....YOUR SQL HERE"
self.env.cr.execute(sql)
self.env.cr.commit()
```

Override the write function in addons/stock/stock.py

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    # Check that we do not modify a stock.move which is done
    frozen_fields = set(['product_qty', 'product_uom', 'product_uos_qty', 'product_uos', 'location_id', 'location_dest_id', 'product_id'])
    for move in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if move.state == 'done':


            #if frozen_fields.intersection(vals):
            #    raise osv.except_osv(_('Operation Forbidden!'),
            #        _('Quantities, Units of Measure, Products and Locations cannot be modified on stock moves that have already been processed (except by the Administrator).'))


    propagated_changes_dict = {}
    #propagation of quantity change
    if vals.get('product_uom_qty'):
        propagated_changes_dict['product_uom_qty'] = vals['product_uom_qty']
    if vals.get('product_uom_id'):
        propagated_changes_dict['product_uom_id'] = vals['product_uom_id']
    #propagation of expected date:
    propagated_date_field = False
    if vals.get('date_expected'):
        #propagate any manual change of the expected date
        propagated_date_field = 'date_expected'
    elif (vals.get('state', '') == 'done' and vals.get('date')):
        #propagate also any delta observed when setting the move as done
        propagated_date_field = 'date'

    if not context.get('do_not_propagate', False) and (propagated_date_field or propagated_changes_dict):
        #any propagation is (maybe) needed
        for move in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if move.move_dest_id and move.propagate:
                if 'date_expected' in propagated_changes_dict:
                    propagated_changes_dict.pop('date_expected')
                if propagated_date_field:
                    current_date = datetime.strptime(move.date_expected, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
                    new_date = datetime.strptime(vals.get(propagated_date_field), DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
                    delta = new_date - current_date
                    if abs(delta.days) >= move.company_id.propagation_minimum_delta:
                        old_move_date = datetime.strptime(move.move_dest_id.date_expected, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
                        new_move_date = (old_move_date + relativedelta.relativedelta(days=delta.days or 0)).strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
                        propagated_changes_dict['date_expected'] = new_move_date
                #For pushed moves as well as for pulled moves, propagate by recursive call of write().
                #Note that, for pulled moves we intentionally don't propagate on the procurement.
                if propagated_changes_dict:
                    self.write(cr, uid, [move.move_dest_id.id], propagated_changes_dict, context=context)
    return super(stock_move, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: Hi phillipstack, it will be better to use ORM. Is there any way with ORM

Comment: I updated the function. I dont know the reason behind the restriction but that might get you over it.

Comment: Hi phillipstack, i don't want to override the function, i need only this at one place. any way to get administrator rights

Comment: If you look at the function above it is hardcoded. Not a security rule. Im not sure if being admin would make a difference. I really think you need to write an sql script to update the record. This is not really security or user group related. The code above says that if the records are frozen and are trying to be updated raise this error. You need to use sql or override the function to get around this.